# Non-constant harmonic function satisfying given property

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u(x,y)$ be a non-constant harmonic function in region $\mathbb{D}_{\mathbb{R}}=: D$ and
$$A:=\{(x,y)\in D : u_x = u_y = 0\} $$
what can one say about the set $A$?

Since $u$ is harmonic, there exists a coharmonic (is this the correct term?) function $v$ and $u,v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations from which:
$$u_x = 0 = v_y\Longrightarrow v=h(x)\quad\mbox{and} -u_y = 0 = v_x\Longrightarrow v=g(y) $$
How do we interpret this? Can a function be only a function of $x$ and only a function of $y$ at the same time? If so, then $v$ is surely constant and that makes $u$ constant. $A=\emptyset$?

..or does it imply that $h,g$ are exactly the same? I'm confused. If they were exactly the same, then by differentiating w.r.t either of $x,y$ we must get $0$. It has to be constant.

Comment: What do you know about the function $z \mapsto u_x(z) - i u_y(z)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer you mean the complex potential?

Comment: I don't know what the complex potential is. Maybe it's that. In any case, I mean the function whose real part is the partial derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$, and whose imaginary part is the negative of the partial derivative of $u$ with respect to $y$.

Comment: @DanielFischer
Disregard the potential, it looked like that on first glance. At any rate, If I pick a $z\in A$, then all I see is it gets turned into $0$. Not sure what you are hinting at :(

Comment: $u \colon D \to \mathbb{C}$. What can you say about $u$? And since $A$ is the zero set of $u$, what follows about $A$?

Comment: You may see better what I'm aiming at if you look at the tags of the question.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668137/the-set-where-a-harmonic-functions-gradient-is-zero)